# Vectorization: iterating over two very large dataframes with non-standard data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, shapely

I have two dataframes in python: one of ~150k *calls*, each with a geographic location, and the other of ~50k *streets*, each with a geographic path. Given the location of each call, I would like to append the head and tail node IDs of the closest street to the call dataframe.

I have read through the call data and converted the numeric lat/long columns and constructed a single Shapely Point column. Likewise I've converted the string path data column into a Shapely LineString. These are algorithms one and two below - unlikely to be the most efficient implementation. Your comments welcome.

```
% Algorithm One: given two columns of latitude & longitude, create a new Point 
def call_iter():
    points = []
    for index, row in calls.iterrows():
        points.append(Point(row['Incident Latitude'], row['Incident Longitude']))
    
    return points % appended to the call dataframe


% Algorithm Two: given a string column containing coordinate data, construct a LineString 
def street_iter():     
    paths = []
    for geo in streets.geometry:
        l = []
        for t in geo.split():
            try:
                t = t.strip('(,)')
                l.append(float(t))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    
        p = []
        for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
            p.append(Point(l[i], l[i+1]))
    
        paths.append(LineString(p))
    return paths  % appended to the street dataframe
```

My primary concern, however, is that outlined in the first paragraph: given the Shapely method `line.distance(point)`, and the newly created Shapely objects, how can I efficiently find the closest street to each call? My day's attempt is shown below. This does work, but it takes 1-2 seconds per call and this is the first of several datasets I'd like to use.

```
% Algorithm Three: find the closest street (head 'u' and tail 'v' nodes) to each call
def build_matrix():
    heads = []
    tails = []

    for i_c, r_c in calls.iterrows():
        print(i)
        p = r_c[4]
        head_min = -1
        tail_min = -1
        dist_min = float('inf')
        min_group = []
    
        for i_s, r_s in streets.iterrows():
            l = r_s[5].distance(p)
            if dist_min > l:
                head_min = r_s['u'] % head node
                tail_min = r_s['v'] % tail node
                dist_min = l
                min_group = []
                min_group.append(r_s)
            if dist_min == l:
                min_group.append(r_s)
            
        if len(min_group) > 1:
            choice = secrets.choice(min_group) % randomly selects an arc
            head_min = choice['u']
            tail_min = choice['v']
        
        heads.append(head_min)
        tails.append(tail_min)

    return (heads, tails) % both appended to the calls dataframe
```

I have spent several hours looking into vectorisation, however I can't find any examples for this sort of thing. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I have spent the morning implementing the work of [Tenkanen et al](https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/L3/04_nearest-neighbour.html). This doesn't seem to have improved efficiency all too much; perhaps to just under a second per iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, got it. Continuing to follow the work of [Tenkanen, Heikinheimo & Aagesen](https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/L3/06_nearest-neighbor-faster.html), and the solution posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389344), I have a solution.

The method ultimately involves a BallTree search to find the nearest *centroid* of each street to each incident (if anyone figures out how to modify this to handle LineStrings, I would appreciate the tip). Implementation below.

```
def get_nearest(src_points, candidates, k_neighbors=1):
    """Find nearest neighbors for all source points from a set of candidate points"""

    # Create tree from the candidate points
    tree = BallTree(candidates, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')

    # Find closest points and distances
    distances, indices = tree.query(src_points, k=k_neighbors)

    # Transpose to get distances and indices into arrays
    distances = distances.transpose()
    indices = indices.transpose()

    # Get closest indices and distances (i.e. array at index 0)
    # note: for the second closest points, you would take index 1, etc.
    closest = indices[0]
    closest_dist = distances[0]

    # Return indices and distances
    return (closest, closest_dist)


def nearest_neighbor(left_gdf, right_gdf, return_vals=False):
    """
    For each point in left_gdf, find closest point in right GeoDataFrame and return them.
    """

    left_geom_col = left_gdf.geometry.name
    right_geom_col = right_gdf.geometry.name

    # Ensure that index in right gdf is formed of sequential numbers
    right = right_gdf.copy().reset_index(drop=True)

    # Parse coordinates from points and insert them into a numpy array as RADIANS
    left_radians = np.array(left_gdf[left_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())
    right_radians = np.array(right[right_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())

    # Find the nearest points
    # -----------------------
    # closest ==> index in right_gdf that corresponds to the closest point
    # dist ==> distance between the nearest neighbors (in meters)

    closest, dist = get_nearest(src_points=left_radians, candidates=right_radians)

    # Return points from right GeoDataFrame that are closest to points in left GeoDataFrame
    closest_points = left_gdf # right.loc[closest]

    # Ensure that the index corresponds the one in left_gdf
    closest_points = closest_points.reset_index(drop=True)

    # Add the head and tail node IDs of the closest street
    if return_vals:
        closest_points['u'] = right.loc[closest,'u'].reset_index(drop=True)
        closest_points['v'] = right.loc[closest,'v'].reset_index(drop=True)

    return closest_points
```